# Using model relationships to find number of responses by a user, to posts of a certain topic type

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a user, a micropost and a response model.

The user has many microposts and has many responses.

Microposts have tags using the acts as taggable gem.

I need to find the number of responses a user has, to microposts that are tagged with a specific tag. To be clear, for example, how many responses has user 1 given to microposts on "exercise"

There is some basic ruby syntax and relationship logic I am missing. This is what I have in my user

This works as a User model method

```
   def user_responses_on_topic(interest)
        microposts = Micropost.tagged_with(interest, :on => :tags )
         count = 0
         microposts.each do |micropost|
         responses =  micropost.responses.size   
         count = count + responses
      end
    count
   end
```

But there's got to be a better rails way?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, it would work if the `#tagged_with` method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, I don't know if you need a `:user_id` in there, but your code didn't hint on any, so I did the same.

```
Response.joins(:micropost).merge(
  Micropost.tagged_with(interest, on: :tags)
).count
```